# VBA SQL query result error

Tags: sql, vba

There's no result or blank excel sheet in result of following SQL query. It works fine if I remove where condition but Its required. So kindly help me to correct my code with where condition. Code is follow-
    Private Sub cmdOpenQuery_Click()

```
Dim strTableName As String
Dim strFieldName As String
Dim strFieldValue As String
Dim strFV As String
Dim strFieldType As String
Dim strBaseSQL As String
Dim strCriteria As String
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim strSQL As String
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim OutPut As String
Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim xlApp As Object

For Each qdf In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
  If qdf.Name = "MyQry" Then
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "MyQry"
 Exit For
 End If
Next

strTableName = Me.[cboSelectTblQry]
strFieldName = Me.[cboWhere]
strFV = Me.[cboEqualto]

strFieldType = CurrentDb.TableDefs(Me.cboSelectTblQry).Fields(Me.cboWhere).Type

If strFieldType = 4 Then
strFieldValue = "[" & strFV & "]"
ElseIf strFieldType = 10 Then
strFieldValue = "['" & strFV & "']"
ElseIf strFieldType = 8 Then
strFieldValue = "[#" & strFV & "#]"
End If


strBaseSQL = "SELECT "

For intCounter = 0 To lstSelectTo.ListCount
lstSelectTo.Selected(intCounter) = True
Next intCounter

For Each varItem In Me![lstSelectTo].ItemsSelected
  strCriteria = strCriteria & "[" & Me![lstSelectTo].ItemData(varItem) & "],"
Next

strSQL = strBaseSQL & Left$(strCriteria, Len(strCriteria) - 1) & " FROM [" &   strTableName & "]" & " Where [" & strFieldName & "] = strFieldValue "

Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("MyQry", strSQL)

If cboFormat = "Excel" Then
OutPut = "D:/Export_" & strTableName & "_" & Date & ".xlsx"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "MyQry", OutPut
MsgBox " File has been exported to " & OutPut

DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmCreateQry"


Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Workbooks.Open (OutPut)
    xlApp.Visible = True

ElseIf cboFormat = "PDF" Then

OutPut = "D:/Export_" & strTableName & "_" & Date & ".pdf"
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "MyQry", acFormatPDF, OutPut, True
MsgBox " File has been exported to " & OutPut

ElseIf cboFormat = "Word" Then



End If

ExitSub:
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
Resume ExitSub
End Sub
```

Comment: `Where [" & strFieldName & "] = strFieldValue "` --> If your `strFieldName` refers to a column that is type numeric, your code will work all the time. If the column is a date or a string you have to surround the `strFieldValue` with `#` or quotes respectively

Comment: @ThomasG - OP attempted to do that if you see lines above the SQL string concatenation. However, the OP enclosed such values in brackets and did not concatenate the VBA variable, `strFieldValue`, but included it in SQL string statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some corrections and it's working now fine for all format like numeric, text and date type.

Following corrections made in Type condition :-

```
If strFieldType = 4 Then
strFieldValue = Me.cboEqualto
ElseIf strFieldType = 10 Then
strFieldValue = "'" & strFV & "'"
ElseIf strFieldType = 8 Then
strFieldValue = "#" & strFV & "#"
End If
```

and following correction in strSQL:-

```
strSQL = strBaseSQL & Left$(strCriteria, Len(strCriteria) - 1) & " FROM [" & strTableName & "]" & " Where [" & strFieldName & "] = " & strFieldValue & ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Your where condition is using strFieldValue as the value to look for. You should instead use the use held by strFieldValue for comparison. You're doing that properly with strTableName already. It is the same idea here. You'd need to enclose the value of strFieldValue in quotes when you add it.

```
strSQL = strBaseSQL & Left$(strCriteria, Len(strCriteria) - 1) & " FROM [" &   strTableName & "]" & " Where [" & strFieldName & "] = '" & strFieldValue & "'"
```

Comment: What is the final value of strSQL before it is executed and what is the error you're receiving?